# Паттерны проектирования в Perl

Tags: ооп, perl, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Значит читаю вакансию perl программиста, написано : высшее образование (не программист, но технарь, инженер - проектировщик), знание Perl (имеется), ООП в perl (имеется), знание mojolicious (тоже), html; xhtml; css; javascript, паттерны проектирования - bullshit, а это зачем? Конечно есть книга банды четырех, но там все примеры для java (который не люблю, а сам синтаксис изучал для понимания примеров), т.е в теории есть понимание, но осуществить средствами языка не получается, или выходит достаточно криво с нагромождением велосипедов. Объясните, есть ли паттерны для perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть, как и для любого языка программирования. Знание паттернов позволяет вам более грамотно и быстро писать нужный код.

[Perl Design Patterns](https://www.perl.com/pub/2003/06/13/design1.html)

Comment: ссылка умерла (. Обновить бы

Comment: @EugenKonkov обновил

Answer (score 0):

В perl тоже можно пользоваться pattern`ами, вот только из-за очень упрощённого ООП, выглядеть они будут совсем иначе. Паттерны по сути это пример правильного использования возможностей ООП, но так как в перле есть только наследование и простенькие объекты, то суть идеи слегка теряется.
Ту же фабрику объектов сделать по шаблону не получится, ибо отсутствуют интерфейсы(вся концепция фабрики как раз в них и кроется). Так что в перле она будет выглядеть как просто динамическое создание объекта(на основании переданного параметра) и его возвращение.

[Perl Design Patterns](http://www.perldesignpatterns.com/) - это довольно старый сайт, к тому же, по моему, он один единственный в этом огромном мире. Идея перл+паттерны как то не очень часто всплывает.

Честно говоря пока не изучил Java, не очень понимал зачем нужны паттерны. Хотя, их ценность именно для перла у меня всё ещё остаётся под вопросом.

Comment: @EcSYZ

    Честно говоря пока не изучил Java, не очень понимал зачем нужны паттерны.

Хорошо сказано. Сравните с утверждением "Design patterns от GoF -- средство для борьбы с недостатками C++/Java/etc". А насчёт их нужности в perl, Ваш вывод перекликается в докладом (кажется) Норвига "Шаблоны проектирования в динамических языках" (слайды у него на сайте).